# php header location - french characters

Tags: php, character-encoding, header, location, special-characters

When the $urlGoBack variable contains a french accented character like "é" the following doesn't work properly, even tho I previously ensured it's being passed on to header like it should, using the mb_convert_encoding() function.

```
header("Location: " . $urlGoBack);
```

The URL I'm being taken to has "é" changed to %E9, which is its URL equivalent I guess.

HTML charset is iso-8859-1, whereas mb_detect_encoding($urlGoBack) returns UTF-8.

On the other hand, if I try converting it with

```
$urlGoBack = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $urlGoBack);
```

or

```
$urlGoBack = mb_convert_encoding($urlGoBack, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
```

then `mb_detect_encoding($urlGoBack)` returns ASCII and "é" is gone, and the URL gets wrong.
Surprisingly tho, it's exactly the same result when I try the seemingly trivial

```
$urlGoBack = mb_convert_encoding($urlGoBack , "UTF-8", "UTF-8");
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: What's your HTML charset and file encoding?

Comment: Is this variable representing a file? 'Cause url addresses do not usually contain accented characters (they're encoded).

Comment: you say you're using french characters in the `Location` header. Are they in the domain or the file path part of the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to encode url like this

header("Location: " . urldecode($urlGoBack));

[Refer php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use urlencode($urlGoBack), like this:

```
header("Location: " . urlencode($urlGoBack));
```

Comment: nope, not solving the problem. I need it to remain "é" in order for the app to work properly, even tho it's not recommended to have it in the URL.

Comment: The URL you're calling, is it on your own site?

Comment: Then you can use urldecode in the receiving script to get your characters back.

Comment: Im trying to avoid that actually, Id need to make several changes then.

Comment: Since those characters aren't legal characters for URLs, you won't have a choice. If you want to keep those characters in your request, you'll have to make those several changes.

Comment: I thought so too, but then I read about swedish and french websites registering with domains including: á, â, ã, ä, å, æ, ç, è, é, ê, ë, ì, í, î, ï, ñ, ò, ó, ô, õ , ö, œ, ù, ú, û, ü, ý, ÿ, ß, ø. Im not sure if its still illegal officially.

Comment: Whoa, where did you see that?

Comment: http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-bugs/087xjy11zw/45657-new-header-problem-with-special-chars-%EF%BF%BD-%EF%BF%BD-and-%EF%BF%BD
http://worldcrunch.com/tech-science/parlez-vous-d-j-le-web-french-accents-invade-urls/c4s5503/#.UHMKYpjA_0e

Comment: Actually, I also know of cyrillic domain names in certain countries that use cyrillic alphabets.